# Using Ajax to calculate fields

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a form where a customer gets a gift certificate that has the value of the product (**not** including taxes) and enters the product number 12345 then selects a ship to address, then has to pay the amount stored in the database to ship the product and add taxes on it and display a total amount.

So I have two points of reference. First is the item lookup done via ajax

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="item_number" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Search" onClick="showResult(item_number.value)" />
```

Lets assume the amount returned from the column 'shipping' in mysql table is $10.00 and the amount for the product is $100.

And then I have the second part which pulls the taxes based on a list of provinces that are selected

```
<div class="right">
            <select class="element select medium" input id="ship_province" name="ship_province" onchange="showTax(this.value)">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="bc">British Columbia</option>
            <option value="alb">Alberta</option>
            <option value="sas">Saskatchewan</option>
            <option value="man">Manitoba</option>
            <option value="ont">Ontario</option>
            <option value="que">Quebec</option>
            <option value="nfl">Newfoundland & Labrador</option>
            <option value="nov">Nova Scotia</option>
            <option value="nwb">New Brunswick</option>
            <option value="pei">Prince Edward Island</option>
            <option value="ykn">Yukon</option>
            <option value="nwt">Northwest Territories</option>
            <option value="nun">Nunavut</option>
            </select>
            <label for="ship_province">Province</label>
        </div>
```

And lets assume the rate returned is 13%.

I can easily return these values in the divs next to the respective fields using this for the item lookup portion

```
function showResult(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getitem.php?sku="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and a similar function for the provinces. The problem I have is 1. displaying these values in another section other than "description" and 2. doing the calculations to the values price,shipping, and tax.

What I'm trying to do is generate a small table where it shows the shipping amount ($10.00),the product price($100.00), the voucher credit (which is just the price of the product),the tax which is calculated on the product price + Shipping.

```
 100 - $item_description
(100) - $voucher_credit
  10 - Shipping
  13% - Tax
--------
24.30
```

What I don't know how to do is have all of this processed on the same page before submitting the form with the payment info. I can do this easily in php but i would have to load this to the next page and then run the script. I am not very familiar with ajax.

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: i usually calculate it for the user using javascript only.  i also calculate server side before storing to the database so the user cant change numbers. you dont need ajax.

Comment: If you're not very familiar with AJAX I would recommend using javascript framework (like jQuery or prototype) to help you out. The documentation is usually pretty good. As far as the calculations go, you should do the calculations in PHP and use javascript/ajax only for displaying (both because javascript isn't available everywhere and because you shouldn't rely on those values --people could change them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't understand what your problem exactly is,
but the way you could implement this could be like this:

1) The customer make the lookup for the product ( Server returns the product description)

2) The customer choose the province

3) Now make a Ajax call to the server (for example: calculateOrder.php). As parameters you pass the product id, the province.

4) The server returns a result set containing all your desired data (price without tax, tax, shipping price, total price which is calculated by price without tax + tax + shipping).
One important thing: Do all calculations on server side, not on client side!!!

5) Display the received result in the browser

6) The user confirm the order by clicking on a button in the browser, and now
the browser sends the data (product, province) to the server (to submitOrder.php) . The server do the same as in step 4) but this time, the server stores the order with any needed information in the database. 
IMPORTANT: Do not pass price and tax from the client to the server. Let the server compute this values, otherwise it would be possible to cheat! For example i could send an order with 0,01$ as price to the server :-)

Answer (score 2):

I use javascript instead of ajax, in a fashion similar to this:

```
    <select class="element select medium" input id="ship_province" name="ship_province" onchange="showTax()">

        <option value="bc" tax=".13" shipping="5.00">British Columbia</option>
        <option value="alb" tax=".10" shipping="10.00">Alberta</option>
    </select>

<script type=text/javascript>
    function showTax(){
        var price=100;
        var tax=Number($('#ship_providence option:selected').attr('tax')) * price;
        var shipping=Number($('#ship_providence option:selected').attr('shipping'));
        alert(price + tax + shipping);

    }
</script>
```

but as i mentioned in the other comment.  you need to recalculate server side before adding values to the database. some users will try to cheat.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know I could set up a "tax" and "shipping" variable in the html section!

Comment: @Fahad, you can set any attribute you want to any element.